# vectorized if in matlab

Tags: matlab, vectorization, conditional-operator

I have a boolean array call it `flag`.

I have two numeric arrays `ifTrue`, `ifFalse`.  All these arrays are the same size, For purposes of this question assume every element in these arrays is unique.

I would like a function `g` with the property that

```
a = g(flag, ifTrue, ifFalse)

all(flag == (a == ifTrue))
all(~flag == (a == ifFalse))
```

Or in English, I would like `g` to return `ifTrue` elements when `flag` is true, and `ifFalse` elements when `flag` is false.

Or, in matlab, I could do this with loops:

```
a = zeros(size(ifTrue));
for i = 1 : numel(ifTrue);
    if flag(i)
         a(i) = ifTrue(i)
    else
         a(i) = ifFalse(i)
    end
end
```

Is there a vectorized approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
%# Given, for example:
ifTrue = 1:10
ifFalse = -ifTrue  
flag = rand(1,10) > 0.5
%# First, set 'a' to ifFalse
a = ifFalse
%# Then override the places where flag is true
a(flag) = ifTrue(flag)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that flag contains ones for true, and zeros for false elements: `a = flag .* ifTrue + (1 - flag) .* ifFalse;`

Comment: It might be worth noting, that this solution doesn't handle Inf's and nan's properly.  The accepted answer does handle that case correctly.